# Trouble loading input into vector type function in C

Tags: c, arrays, vector

Ive created a vector in C that holds chars. The point is to ask a user for input from keyboard and have them input one char at a time, then add it to the vector using calloc.It currently does not load anything and quits after any input.  I want to be able to keep adding characters until the user inputs return in place of a character then, the program will turn the characters into a string and append to text that is preset. After it will print out the result. My issue is that my program won't load the user input into the vector array. The final result should look like HW4 Input: 123456

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 //declare a new vector structure
int arraySize =1;

char *vector(char *Array){
    arraySize++;
    void *temp=(char*) calloc(arraySize, sizeof(char));
    Array= (char*) temp;
    return Array;
}

int main(void){
    int i, m;
    int h=0;
    int index=0;
    char c;
    char *array = (char *) calloc(arraySize, sizeof(char));
    array[0] = '\0';
    char ch[]= "HW4 input: ";
    printf("\nEnter a single character to add to the string\n");
    printf("Enter one character at a time, when done press enter without any other input.\n");
    while((c=getc(stdin))!='\n'){
        array[index]=c;
        index++;
        if(index<arraySize){
            char *temp=(char*) calloc(arraySize, sizeof(char));
            memcpy(temp,array, arraySize);
            array=vector(array);
            memcpy(array, temp, arraySize);
        }
    }

    arraySize++;
    array=vector(array);
    index++;
    array[index]='\0';
    char output[arraySize+14];
    for (i=0; i<strlen(ch); i++){
        output[i]= ch[i];
    }

    for(m=i; m<strlen(output); m++){
        output[m]=array[h];
    }

    printf("\n%c\n", array[0]);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: punctuationisaveryimportantthingtomakeyourquestionunderstandable. Not only in your text, but also in your code (use spaces!)

Comment: And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: or cast it.  It's fine.

Comment: "my program won't load the user input into the vector array". So what does it do instead? Please describe the input, the expected output/result and the actual output/result.

Comment: @xaxxon: No, it is not. Please read the corresponding question here to get some understanding. C is not C++ (and in C++ you should not use that cast anyway).

Comment: Aside: `char c;` --> `int c;` because `getc()` returns `int`.

Comment: You are only allocating ***1 byte*** of memory to `char * array` but you then index it by an incrementing `index`. You try to deal with it by overwriting the pointer with an allocation to more memory. That will cause memory leaks since you have lost the previous pointer to be able to `free` it.

Comment: `if(index<arraySize)` shouldn't that be `if(index>=arraySize)` and shouldn't `arraySize++` be done before calling `calloc`to increase the vector size? BTW, you may want to consider using [`realloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc).

Comment: `if(index<arraySize)` --> `if(index>=arraySize)`

Comment: Here: `for(m=i; m<strlen(output); m++)` you control the loop with the buffer that is written to. `output` is an uninitialised automatic variable, which very likely will contain garbage, hance you can't call `strlen` on it, which requires it to be null-terminated. After constructing `output`, you shoul add the terminator, `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you write

```
index++;
if (index<arraySize) {
...
```

however at start arraySize==1 so that condition will never be true.

Allocating memory is a costly operation therefore to allocate every byte and then copy over the contents is not effective.

Instead allocate say 100 characters and then if the user input is longer add another 100 character. The most convenient way to do this is to use realloc.

e.g.

```
if (index < arraySize)
{
  char* tmp = realloc(array, arraySize + 100)
  if (tmp != NULL)
  {
    array = tmp;
    arraySize += 100;
  }
  else 
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
  }
}
```

you can always reallocate again with the correct size once the user is finished with his input to get the right buffer size.